# Why does d3.max() output second largest number?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a bar chart with d3.js. The datasets I used output wrong max value so I tested with the following sets again.

```
name,value
us,1000
china,800
uk,850
spain,700
italy,400
france,400
belgium,300
```

But when I run my script below, the output is `850`, not `1000`. What's happening?

```js
csv(filepath).then(data => {
    let top = max(data, d => d.value);
    console.log(top)
    render(data)                                        // refer to formerly created function render()
});
```

Comment: You have more than 15rp now, so please upvote the answer you got, it explains your issue. For a very quick idiomatic D3 fix, just do: `csv(filepath, d3.autoType).etc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to be sure  that d.value is a number and not a string, if not it will give you the alphabetic max between string '850' and '1000'

one way can be to `parseInt` your data to compared it as number value and get the correct max

```
csv(filepath).then(data => {
    let top = max(data, d => parseInt(d.value, 10));
    console.log(top)
    render(data)                                        // refer to formerly created function render()
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the radix when using `parseInt`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: thank you i edit my reply to add the radix